# Python: Iterate over list, making each list value its own separate dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list:

```
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
```

I want to take each of these list values and make them their own separate dictionaries:

```
Alice = {}
Bob = {}
Charlie = {}
```

I need to be able to iterate over the list and do this programatically so that it's not hard-coded, and can be done on any arbitrary list.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It should almost certainly be a dictionary, not a bunch of variables: `people = {name: {} for name in ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']}`, then you access with `people['Alice']` etc.

Comment: Agreeing with other commenters. Dynamically named/referenced variables (a.k.a. "variable variables") are a huge anti-pattern and every time you think of them as a solution, think "dictionary" instead.